# Изменение компилируемого файла средствами CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

У меня есть `C/C++` файл `functions.cpp`. Как с помощью `CMake` скомпилировать только определённые функции из этого файла?

То есть вместо:

```
add_library(my_lib functions.cpp)
```

Надо что-то вроде:

```
add_library(my_lib some_functions.cpp)
```

Возможно, надо скопировать исходный файл и удалить из него ненужные функции? Как это сделать средствами `CMake`?

Содержимое файла может меняться, список нужных функций тоже, изменять `functions.cpp` для этих целей я не могу, поэтому необходимо делать это на этапе сборки, а не вручную создавать новый файл `some_functions.cpp` всякий раз, включая только нужные функции из общего хедера.

Comment: Зачем это вам понадобилось? Может вам обычная conditional compilation с макросами нужен? Просто так функции нельзя выбрать.

Comment: А зачем? Если `functions` настолько огромен, есть смысл разбить его на отдельные единицы трансляции. `CMake` - утилита автоматизации сборки, и исходный код - не ее уровень абстракции.

Comment: @mkkik я же говорю, что не могу изменять проект для этих целей, а единственный доступный инструмент - `CMake`.

Comment: @user7860670 если это означает добавление макросов в `functions.cpp`, то нет. Неужели нельзя попарсить с помощью `CMake` файл?

Comment: конечно нет... парсинг .cpp - это неподъемная задача. Даже компиляторы с этим справляются с большим трудом. Так а зачем вам исключать ненужные функции? Ну скомпилируются, а потом неиспользуемые все равно будут выкинуты.

Comment: @user7860670 в первую очередь время компиляции. А во вторых мне нужен только определённый функционал из библиотеки и если разработчик `functions.cpp` изменяет ненужную мне функцию, я делаю пул и у меня не должна происходить перекомпиляция из-за этого. "парсинг .cpp - это неподъемная задача" - но я же знаю имена нужных мне функций, в чём проблема найти подстроки в строке?

Comment: А парсинг .cpp не сводится к поиску подстроки в строке. А зная имена нужных вам функций вы не можете просто так определить, какие из функций в файле нужны для компиляции нужных вам функций. А вообще тут у вас явно проблема XY проступает - вы страдаете от долгого времени компиляции и пытаетесь как-то наладить инкрементально-частичную сборку вместо того чтобы позаботится об общем ускорении сборки чтобы не парится и  перекомпилировать все с нуля после каждого пула.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью директив препроцессора и cmake-команды `add_compile_definitions()`. Например, так я писал кроссплатформенные функции для работы с текстом (кодировками):

**В CMakeLists.txt:**

```
add_compile_definitions(Linux=1 Windows=2)
if (UNIX)
    add_compile_definitions(OS=Linux)
elseif (WIN32)
    add_compile_definitions(OS=Windows)
endif ()
```

**В коде:**

```
#if OS == Linux
    /* code */
#elif OS == Windows
    /* code */
#endif
```